# R creating a list of JSON's from a DF

Tags: r, json

I have a data.frame like the following:

```
rnum  Field  Value  
1        Car   25.2
1        Bike 20.1
1        Taxi  100.1
2        Car   25.5   
2        Bike  19.1
2        Taxi  25.7
```

I want to create a list of JSON such that, each element of the list is a JSON object is grouped by rnum.
Essentially one element of the list should look like this:

```
{"Car":25.2,"Bike":20.1,"Taxi":100.1,"rnum":"1"}
```

I tried `df %>%group_by(rnum)%>%toJSON()` but it yields 3 JSON entries for each row.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `group_split` with 'rnum', loop over the `list` with `map`, create a named `list`, apply the `toJSON` and flatten it to a single `character` vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
library(tibble)
out <- df1 %>%
    group_split(rnum, .keep = FALSE) %>% 
    map_chr( ~ toJSON(as.list(deframe(.x)), auto_unbox = TRUE))
```

-output

```
cat(out, '\n')
#{"Car":25.2,"Bike":20.1,"Taxi":100.1} {"Car":25.5,"Bike":19.1,"Taxi":25.7}
```

---

Or using `xtabs` from `base R`

```
toJSON(as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(Value ~ rnum + Field, df1)))
#[{"Bike":20.1,"Car":25.2,"Taxi":100.1},{"Bike":19.1,"Car":25.5,"Taxi":25.7}]
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
toJSON(dcast(setDT(df1), rnum ~ Field))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(rnum = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Field = c("Car", 
"Bike", "Taxi", "Car", "Bike", "Taxi"), Value = c(25.2, 20.1, 
100.1, 25.5, 19.1, 25.7)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Widen it first:

```r
df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(rnum, names_from="Field", values_from="Value") %>%
  jsonlite::toJSON()
# [{"rnum":1,"Car":25.2,"Bike":20.1,"Taxi":100.1},{"rnum":2,"Car":25.5,"Bike":19.1,"Taxi":25.7}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another base R option using `reshape`, e.g.,

```
gsub(
  "Value\\.",
  "",
  toJSON(reshape(df, direction = "wide", idvar = "rnum", timevar = "Field"))
)
```

which gives

```
[{"rnum":1,"Car":25.2,"Bike":20.1,"Taxi":100.1},{"rnum":2,"Car":25.5,"Bike":19.1,"Taxi":25.7}]
```